# Vuex store getter always returning false

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am new to Vue js, and also with Vuex. I am having trouble accessing store getters,
[image]

You can see in getter, Activated is true, And In My getter in store.js is

```
 getters: {
loggedIn(state) {
  return state.token !== null
},
Activated(state) {
  return state.activated;
},
```

You can see state activated also is true,
But when I access by

```
store.getters.Activated
```

It always return false, but When I access another getter logged in by same method in same function it gives the value true.

```
store.getters.loggedIn
```

Where I tried to access this in

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
  if (!store.getters.loggedIn) {
    next({
      name: 'home',
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
} 
else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresActivation)) {
  debugger;
  if (store.getters.Activated===true) {
    next()
  } else {
    next({
      name: 'activate',
    })
  }
}
else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
  if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
    next({
      name: 'activate',
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
} else {
  next()
}
```

})

mutation in store js

```
mutations: {
updateFilter(state, filter) {
  state.filter = filter
},

retrieveToken(state, token) {
  state.token = token
},
CheckActivation(state, value) {
  state.activated = value
},
destroyToken(state) {
  state.token = null
}},
```

and actions

```
actions: {
CheckActivation(context){
  if(this.token===null){
    context.commit('CheckActivation', false)
    return false;
  }
  else{
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://vuejs.test/api/user",
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+ this.state.token,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }
    }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      if(response.verified)
      context.commit('CheckActivation', true)
      else
      context.commit('CheckActivation', false)
    });
  }
},
```

Please Help.

Comment: Is state.activated initially set to true?

Comment: nope, it is set to false initially.

Comment: can you provide the code where you access the store?

Comment: ok will add in the main question

Comment: From where is activated set to true.Please add mutation update code as well as the mutation.

Comment: ok, I will add that also

Comment: First of all you are using getters wrong. If getter doesn't do anything but is just passing data from state just use `store.state.activated`.

Comment: Nope using state also did not helped. And how I am using getters wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So it's most probably because you would be accessing the store variable before it is set to true .
For accurate solution please add code of mutation of above variable and method call.May be you will need to use async await in actions of store and in method call of vue file.